# dashes vs underscores in URL

Tags: url-rewriting, naming-conventions

In URL rewriting, i am quite confused that should i use underscore **(_)** OR hyphen **(-)**  to replace spaces. According to [**this**](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/15/dashes-vs-underscores-in-urls.aspx) and [**this**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes.html), hyphen should be used.
But [**wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/) uses underscores like en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network_programming. so which should be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use dashes

read from the matt's blog
http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/

Comment: @coder matt's blog says that dashes are considered 1 word, while hyphen represent multiple word, but google consider web-site as a single word.

Comment: @developer no, it does not. A dash is a hyphen. You're confusing underscore with dash. this_is_one_word this-is-multiple-words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want. It doesn't matter (from a technical point of view; there may be other reasons to choose one over the other).

Comment: check the matt's blog. he has some explanation.

Comment: @coder Yes ... He has some information if you care about SEO specifically related to how he says Google implements things at the time he wrote that entry. Nevertheless, the accuracy of my statement remains, in general.

Comment: Try a search in google for web_site vs web-site. As far as seo is concerned, there is a difference...

Comment: @Bran Whitlock - I agree, I probably should've specified that I meant there was no *technical* reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: I gave you a +1.  All that matters is conformance to RFC 3986 and RFC 3987.

Comment: It does matter! Except you don't care about SEO and number of your visitors. Search engines like dashes far better.